# Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):

Tags: css, webpack, postcss-loader, angular14

When i run ng server i have those errors:

The point is that i am trying to update angular 13 to angular 14, however, if i do not user webpack i have a problem with @ in css and looking for info i found that i need a loader so i thought that i should use webpack but i have those errors. Is there a way to solve them?

```
SyntaxError
(2:7) C:\Proyectos\NOID\Project\node_modules\@xbs\webix-pro\webix.min.css Unknown word
  1 | 
> 2 |       import API from "!../../style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js";
    |       ^
  3 |       import domAPI from "!../../style-loader/dist/runtime/styleDomAPI.js";
  4 |       import insertFn from "!../../style-loader/dist/runtime/insertBySelector.js";**
```

This is my custom-webmack.config:

```
const path = require('path');

     module.exports = {
       output: {
         filename: "[name].scss",
         path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
       },
       module: {
        rules: [

          {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
              loader: "babel-loader",
            }
          },
          {
            test: /\.(sass|css|scss)$/,
            use: [
              'style-loader',
              'css-loader',
              {
                loader: "postcss-loader",
                options: {
                  plugins: () => [
                    require("autoprefixer")()
                  ],
                },
              },
              'sass-loader',
            ]
          },
          {
            test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$/,
            use: {
              loader: 'file-loader',
              options: {
                name: '[name].[ext]',
                publicPath: 'images',
                outputPath: 'images',
              }
            }
          },
        ]
      },
     };
```

this is package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ingesys-apps-manager",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.1401.1",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^14.1.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.1.1",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^14.0.0-beta.40",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0",
    "@angular/localize": "^14.1.1",
    "@angular/material": "^14.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "^14.1.1",
    "@mdi/js": "^6.5.95",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.5",
    "@types/bignumber.js": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.39",
    "@types/jqueryui": "^1.12.15",
    "@types/pako": "^1.0.1",
    "@types/rx": "^4.1.2",
    "@types/select2": "^4.0.53",
    "@xbs/filemanager": "^9.4.2",
    "@xbs/webix-pro": "^9.4.2",
    "angular-split": "^3.0.3",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "bignumber.js": "^9.0.1",
    "bluebird": "^3.7.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.0-beta1",
    "buffer": "^5.7.1",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "dateformat": "^3.0.3",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "highcharts": "^10.1.0",
    "html-to-image": "^1.6.1",
    "i": "^0.3.7",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "jquery-ui-dist": "^1.12.1",
    "jqwidgets-framework": "^8.3.2",
    "jqwidgets-ng": "^12.2.1",
    "jqwidgets-scripts": "^8.3.2",
    "json-bigint": "^1.0.0",
    "jstoxml": "^2.0.5",
    "jszip": "^3.9.1",
    "jszip-utils": "^0.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "material-icons": "^1.11.8",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.33",
    "murmurhash": "^1.0.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^8.0.0",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^7.5.0",
    "ngx-drag-drop": "^2.0.0",
    "ngx-image-compress": "^8.0.4",
    "ngx-logger": "^4.2.2",
    "ngx-mat-select-search": "^3.3.3",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "6.1.0",
    "ngx-store": "^3.1.1",
    "ngx-xml2json": "^1.0.2",
    "npm": "^8.16.0",
    "pako": "^1.0.11",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "resize-observer-polyfill": "^1.5.1",
    "rxjs": "^7.5.6",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.8",
    "sass": "^1.54.3",
    "secure-web-storage": "^1.0.2",
    "select2": "^4.0.13",
    "streamsaver": "^2.0.6",
    "ts-md5": "^1.2.7",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "widget": "^0.0.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular-builders/dev-server": "^7.3.1",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.1.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^14.1.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "^14.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "^14.1.1",
    "@angular/elements": "^14.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.1.1",
    "@types/bootstrap": "^5.1.11",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.5",
    "@types/json-bigint": "^1.0.1",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.182",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.50",
    "ajv": "^8.8.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "exports-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^4.3.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.20",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "lodash.get": "^4.4.2",
    "lodash.isequal": "^4.5.0",
    "lodash.merge": "^4.6.2",
    "lodash.set": "^4.3.2",
    "postcss-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^13.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "^5.20.1",
    "typescript": "4.6.4",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "worker-plugin": "^5.0.1"
  }
}
```

this is angujar.json (the beggining)

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "Project": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "custom-webpack.config.js",
              "replaceDuplicatePlugins": true
            },
            "aot": true,
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "rxjs"
            ],
            "outputPath": "dist/Project",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/assets/scss"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "./src/styles.css",
              "./node_modules/select2/dist/css/select2.css",
              "./src/assets/styles/jqx.base.css",
              "./src/assets/styles/jqx.light-ingeteam.css",
              "./src/assets/styles/jqx.tree-light-ingeteam.css",
              "./src/assets/scss/style.scss",
              "./node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.min.css",
              "./node_modules/@xbs/webix-pro/webix.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "./node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.min.js",
              "./node_modules/select2/dist/js/select2.js",
              "./node_modules/moment/moment.js",
              "./node_modules/moment-timezone/moment-timezone.js",
              "./node_modules/@xbs/webix-pro/webix.min.js"
            ],
            "webWorkerTsConfig": "tsconfig.worker.json",
```

and this is postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('autoprefixer'),
    require('postcss-import'),
  ]
}
```

I think that the problem is related with the use of postcss-loader but i do not know where it is

Comment: Hi. Were you able to figure out the issue?